# Finding digits of large numbers when changing number base?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $2003^{2009}$+$2009^{2017}$+$2015^{2025}$ in base 3, we get the very long string $a_{n} a_{n-1}... a_{1} a_{0}$. What are the values of the last 3 digits $a_2, a_1, a_0$?

Comment: Consider $\mod 27.$

Comment: It's easy to find $a_0.$ Just reduce modulo $3.$

Answer (score 2):

The last three "digits" in the mod 3 representation of a numbeer $x$ tell us what $x \mod 27$ is.

So determine what $2003^{2009} \pmod{27}$ is and similarly for the two other powers, and this is not too hard as $2003 \pmod{27}=5$ and $\phi(27)=18$ and $2009 \pmod {18} = 11$ so we only need to find $5^{11} \pmod{27}$ which equals $2$.

Similarly the other terms are $11$ and $26\equiv -1$ and so we get $12$ in total, and so last digits `110` $1\times 3^2 + 1\times 3^1 + 0\times 3^0$.

Comment: @nasdasasdas yes, the higher digits represent items that late 0 modulo $m^n$.